# Windows 8 NFC ISO specification support

Tags: windows-store-apps, nfc, iso

I am new to NFC. I need to implement point of sale NFC application in [Windows 8 Tablet](http://www.asus.com/vivo/en/vivoTab.htm). I could find that windows 8 limited NFC  support

for [ISO 14443/ISO7816](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx/Public/NfcComparison.xlsx?cid=403e226884c13853&id=documents&app=Excel&authkey=!AD3x_SB0zWCf0mU&).

I would like to know, is it possible to develop a point of sale application in Windows 8 tablet which can communicate to a NFC smart card using ISO 14443/ISO7816.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 has "support" for NFC via their [Proximity API](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731). However this has two issues: It only works for Windows Store apps. Also, the Proximity highly abstract the underlying details of NFC from the application developer. There isn't really a concept of a tag, you are just handed a message (NdefMessage) via an event model.

Most people use [PC/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) which gives you very low-level access. PC/SC is what the [GoToTags Windows NFC App](http://support.gototags.com/hc/en-us/categories/200030816-GoToTags-Windows-NFC-App) uses. You could also use of the NFC reader SDKs if you are OK with being tied to a specific NFC reader.

DISCLAMER: I am the CEO of GoToTags